# SetImageResource not visible in android

Tags: android, image

i am developing an application , in which i need to change four images randomly by checking condition. its working for four different values(ex : 2,4,1,3), but if i am using 
 five values for four images (ex: 2,3,3,1,4). Then, i am unable to identify the difference of changing image two times.

i am using the following code.

```
                            if(id==0 || id==4) //here 0,4 appears sequencially then 
                                               // blue image not changed two times.

                               {
                                light1.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_on);
                                light2.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_off);
                                light3.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_off);
                                light4.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_off);
                            }
                            else if(id==1 || id==5)
                            {
                                light1.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_off);
                                light2.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_on);
                                light3.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_off);
                                light4.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_off);
                            }
                            else if(id==2 || id==6)
                            {
                                light1.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_off);
                                light2.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_off);
                                light3.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_on);
                                light4.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_off);
                            }
                            else if(id==3 || id==7)
                            {
                                light1.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_off);
                                light2.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_off);
                                light3.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_off);
                                light4.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_on);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
light1.setImageResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

insted of

```
light1.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_off);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) to detect the change

You can use it in [View.StartAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startAnimation%28android.view.animation.Animation%29)